# Website responsiveness stops working at 450px width. Can this be fixed using Simple CSS in WordPress Gutenburg Editor?

Tags: css, wordpress

I do marketing and communications for a small company where everyone wears many hats and I'm trying to independently make our blog a more user-friendly experience.

Here's the blog: https://blog.thrively.com

The website runs on WordPress using a third-party theme called Creative Child (I don't think this matters).

I've been able to make simple CSS changes within WordPress' Gutenburg editor, but I'm stuck trying to make the mobile experience responsive.

When I "inspect" on desktop and select the mobile view, I've discovered everything responds correctly until the width reaches 450px. At that point, the text just runs off the page to the right.

Here is the code that currently exists in the Simple CSS customization window where there is a "@"media section that applies to all screens less than 770px wide (this was here before I started with the company), so I thought there might be something in there that needs something added. Nothing I've tried has worked yet though.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
/* Enter Your Custom CSS Here */

#menu-primary-items {
    position: relative;
    top: unset;
    left: unset;
}

#menu-primary-items .menu-item a {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.wf-active .page-id-12165 .entry-title {
    display: none;
}

.wf-active .page-id-12165 .entry-content img {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 770px){
        
    .post-meta {display: none;
        
    }
        
    .post-details {display: none;
        
    }

    .site-header .logo{
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .headroom{
        margin-top: 0px !important;
    }
    
    .menu-items{
        top: 170px !important;
    }
    
    #masthead .site-header-container{
        background: #fff;
    }
    
    .mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .header-button-wrapper{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    #masthead {
    position: absolute !important;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
    }
.primary ul a, .primary ul a:visited{
        color:#333333;
}
        
    
}
#primary .entry-title a{
        text-align: left !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    line-height: 1.3em !important;
}
.primary ul a, .primary ul a:visited{
        color:#333333;
}
.site-header #blog-title{
        color:#333333;
}
#primary .entry-title a{
        padding-top:10px;
}

#menu-primary-items .menu-item a{
        top: -165px !important;
}

.post p{margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.post content-width{width: 550px
}

.wp-block-cover {margin-bottom: 25px !important;
}

.wp-block-separator {margin-top: 20px !important; margin-bottom: 20px !important}

.entry-content{width: 650px !important;
}

.entry-title {
    display: none;
}

.wp-block-cover__inner-container {width:80%; line-height: 50%
}

.wp-caption {display: none;
}

.entry-content ul {text-indent: -25px !important; margin-left: 25px !important; margin-bottom: 25px !important;
}

.entry-content ol {text-indent: -25px !important; margin-left: 25px !important; margin- bottom: 25px !important;
}

.col-md-5 {display: none;
}
```

[Preview at 452px wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8S4g.png)

[Preview at 448px wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19cqP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following style to css file.

```
#primary section.entry-content{ max-width: 100%; }
```

it will solve the issue

Comment: Thank you!!! Such a relief.